# Auto-sync killing battery all of a sudden on S3?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have had my S3 for a good long while, ever since they were new with Verizon. Almost immediately, I bought an extended battery and all was good. In the last week or so, the battery has begun discharging rapidly. 50% in a couple of hours. I had extra batteries, so I switched out thinking I had a bad one. Same deal.

Looking around, I read that killing the cache should fix it. Nope. Then someone suggested turning off auto-sync. That did it. Battery drain want back to normal. Why? Why all of a sudden? Then, the Gmail app doesn’t want to manually sync… Annoying. I was hoping to avoid a factory reset, but would that be my next course of action? I’m wondering if the Gmail app is bad. Definitely going to dump that and re-install.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it just the gmail app? Or are other auto-sync apps also guilty of battery murder?

Comment: Settings → More → Battery will show you which app(s) use the most battery. Check there, and then update your question with what you found out.

Answer (score 1):

> It is not "Constantly" trying to update, and therefore it is not
>   constantly using your battery.
>
> Autosync only transmits when the other side has something to send. It
>   doesn't constantly ask if there has been a change that needs to be
>   synced.
>
> This is accomplished by opening a socket to the server, then putting
>   the radio to sleep. The socket stays open until server attempts to
>   send something, or the socket times out. TCP/IP sockets typically time
>   out anywhere from 12 to 18 minutes after they are opened.
>
> Each time the radio listens for traffic (which in GSM land is every
>   120 milliseconds) it will see that traffic is waiting if EITHER the
>   socket timed out or the socket became readable (has data waiting). It
>   would then power up the radio enough to read the data, or reestablish
>   the timed out socket).
>
> Your phone is doing that all the time, 24/7 365 whether you have
>   autosync on or not. That's how cell phones work. It takes virtually
>   zero power.
>
> So if you sync your Gmail, Contacts, Calendars, Picasa, Documents,
>   Books, Music, Reader, all of those things you sync with Google are
>   handled by ONE socket. That one socket gets set readable when there
>   has been any change in any of those services that needs syncing.
>
> Add another socket for Dropbox, or skydrive, or any non-Google mail
>   accounts.
>
> (For non-google mail accounts ALWAYS choose IMAP accounts, never POP3.
>   Pop3 has to wake up and check mail. Have your gmail account pull mail
>   from pop3, and get that account off your phone. IMAP accounts use IMAP
>   IDLED, which works on the open socket method described above, as does
>   Microsoft Exchange).
>
> The vast majority of these services go hours if not days between any
>   changes, so there are very few times that data needs to actually be
>   synced. Most of the time its just a socket refresh. And all of these
>   tend to happen at one time, because Android tries to get them to all
>   drop at the same time by starting them at the same time when you
>   bounce from one tower to the next or switch from cellular to wifi.
>
> But the key point to remember is that your phone is ALWAYS talking to
>   the towers anyway, every 120ms, so these socket refreshes take almost
>   zero extra power.

Source: icebike's answer on http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-x/181151-autosync-battery-killer.html

Comment: Wow! That is a great answer. Thank you, you really helped me with understanding this functionality. But this being said, why do you think the dramatic battery drain slows (dramatically) with auto-sync turned off?

Answer (score 1):

I hava a Samsung S5. Before I charged my phone once per 24 or 48 hours and since a few days suddently the battery lasted only 4 to 8 hours. After several test I discovered the cause was a few corrupt images. I deleted the corrupt images and the problem was solved. I used [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tostis.corruptimagefinder) to find the corrupt images.